# How can I retrieve Data from a database by using the URL

Tags: python, json, api, routes, getmethod

I want to type the CallId in the URL and get the information of the row from my database in Json Format.
For example typing: http://127.0.0.1:5000/caller/?CallId=123456 and then get the OriginationName and OriginationNumber.

I think there is a mistake in my for loop.
i would be very grateful for any help.
 Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import yaml

anrufe = Flask(__name__)

datenbank = yaml.load(open('datenbank.yaml'))
anrufe.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = datenbank['mysql_host']
anrufe.config['MYSQL_USER'] = datenbank['mysql_user']
anrufe.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = datenbank['mysql_password']
anrufe.config['MYSQL_DB'] = datenbank['mysql_db']

mysql = MySQL(anrufe)


@anrufe.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userDetails = request.form
        CallId = userDetails['CallId']
        OriginationNumber = userDetails['OriginationNumber']
        OriginationName = userDetails['OriginationName']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO caller(CallId,OriginationNumber,OriginationName) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)",
                    (CallId, OriginationNumber, OriginationName))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return 'Der Anrufer wurde registriert'

    return render_template('index.html')

@anrufe.route('/caller/all')
def caller():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    resultValue = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM caller")
    if resultValue > 0:
        userDetails = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('caller.html', userDetails=userDetails)


@anrufe.route('/caller/", methods=['GET'])
def api_caller():
    if 'CallId' in request.args:
        CallId = int(request.args['CallId'])
        print(CallId)
    else:
        return "Error: No CallId field provided. Please specify a CallId."

    results = []

    for caller in datenbank:
        if caller['CallId'] == ['CallId']:
            results.append(caller)

    return jsonify(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    anrufe.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: `@anrufe.route('/caller/", methods=['GET'])` you have different `'` and `"` for caller. Just use one type (either `"/caller/"` either `'/caller/'`).

Comment: Thank you but it still doesnt work . "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str." This is what i get .

Comment: Then it means that what one of your (desired) list slicings - userDetails['CallId'] or userDetails['OriginationNumber']  etc is in fact a string; aka userDetails or userDetails is a string not a list (mentioned above are only examples) - add the full error to the question or post it here, it should say where the error was triggered

Comment: File "/home/omid/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    File "/home/omid/flaskapp/anrufe.py", line 54, in api_caller
    if caller['CallId'] == ['CallId']:
    TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: if you add a print(caller) before the if, what does the print say? The error tells that `caller` is a string, not a dictionary as intended. If you show the caller (from print) we will get to the bottom of this.

Comment: What do you mean by ''  show the caller'' ?

Comment: add `print(caller)` before if `caller['CallId'] == ['CallId']` and after `for caller in datenbank`, but now lookin at that expression I think I got the answer

Comment: i get a syntax error    for caller in datenbank:
        print(caller) if caller['CallId'] == ['CallId']:
            results.append(caller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1: let's get all results by callerid:

```
from flask import jsonify

@anrufe.route('/caller/CallId=<id>', methods = ['GET'])
def api_caller(id):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    resultValue = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM caller WHERE CallId =  (%s)",(id,))
    if resultValue > 0:
        user_by_id = cur.fetchall()
        return jsonify(user_by_id)
    else:
        return "Called ID does not exist!"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212220/discussion-on-answer-by-andreis11-how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-a-database-by-usi).